# Unable to provide access permission to file because of incorrect path in docker file

Tags: java, docker, chmod

I am trying to prepare a docker image of java service. But while building the image I am getting below error.

```
chmod: cannot access '/HerculesServiceOnboarding-linux': No such file or directory
```

HerculesServiceOnboarding-linux is a binary file which being called to execute within java service. File is under the path src/main/java/resources/ . The usual maven project structure.

Below is the project structure of my java service.

[image]

**Below is the docker file code.**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jre-openj9

ARG app=hercules-onboarding-job

ENV app $app

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y --no-install-recommends upgrade \
&& apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install locales \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8" \
LANGUAGE="en_US:en" \
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" \
VERSION=8 \
UPDATE=222 \
BUILD=10

COPY  /target/$app.jar /javaAction/target/
COPY log4Olympus2.xml /

RUN chmod +x /HerculesServiceOnboarding-linux -- **Failed on this line with above mentioned error**
# RUN chmod +x /target/classes/HerculesServiceOnboarding-linux -- getting the same error
#RUN chmod +x /target/$app.jar/HerculesServiceOnboarding-linux -- getting the same error

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/javaAction/target/hercules-onboarding-job.jar"]
```

I don't know what will be the right path to access the file? Whatever path I have to provide should not be environment specific as this will deployed to multiple envs.

**Request your help to provide me the right path to access the file!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every commands within the RUN clause will be executed in the image you are buildind, thus on your openjre, with all files/dirs your may have added in the meantime.

In your case, when the build command reaches your chmod, so far you have  :

```
/javaAction/target/hercules-onboarding-job.jar
/everthing/else/provided/with/openjre
```

Thus, you cannot expect it to find a file that is not present... yet.
All you have to do is COPY/ADD the desired file (or directory if more is needed) the same way your did with your jar... or it it is the *jar*   itself whose rights you want to "*chmod*", then fix your chmod with the correct path.

And if you don't want it to remain in your image, you can juste remove it at the end of your build, with a *RUN rm -rf ...* command

Comment: Adding the files using copy command solves my issue. Thanks for the knowledge.